# Question on affine varieties and zero locus.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

From my book in algebraic geometry:

"Let $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety with coordinate ring $A(Y)$ (note that we consider $\mathbb{A}^n$ with the zariski topology), furthermore let $f: k[x_1,...,x_n] \to A(Y)$ be the canonical homomorphism. If $I \subset A(Y)$ is an ideal, we define its zero locus $\mathscr{L}(I) \subset Y$ to be the zero locus of $f^{-1}(I)$, note that $\mathscr{I}(Y) \subset f^{-1}(I)$ so that the zero locus of $f^{-1}(I)$ is indeed contained in $Y$."

I get everything except the final conclusion. How does $\mathscr{I}(Y) \subset f^{-1}(I)$ imply that the zero locus of $f^{-1}$ is contained in $Y$? Indeed we have $\mathscr{L}(f^{-1}(I)) \subset \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{I}(Y))$, but how is it contained in $Y$? I just don't get it..

Comment: $V(I(Y))=Y$, so there you go. (Out of curiousity, what source uses `$\mathscr{L}$` = $\mathscr{L}$ for the operation of taking the vanishing locus of an ideal?)

Comment: @KReiser I am reading some notes by Ben Moonen, I think he uses them to eventually make a book out of it. Can be found at his homepage.

Thanks for pointing out the equality. This holds as long as $Y$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ when considering the zariski topology? Or does the equality hold for any subset $Y$?

Comment: I'd encourage you to think that one through on your own - here's the answer in [rot13](https://rot13.com/): gnxvat gur mreb ybphf vf nyjnlf pybfrq, naq va snpg bar pna cebir gung gur inavfuvat ybphf bs gur vqrny bs shapgvbaf inavfuvat ba fbzr frg nyjnlf ergheaf rknpgyl gur pybfher. Fb gur fbyhgvba vf jura $Y$ vf n pybfrq fhofrg va gur Mnevfxv gbcbybtl.

Comment: I checked out Moonen's notes and it looks like the character in question is actually `$\mathscr{Z}$`=$\mathscr{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to think about it. There is a bijective correspondence between the ideals $\overline{I}$ of $A(Y)$ and the ideals $I$ of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ that contain $I(Y)$ given by $I = f^{-1}(\overline{I})$. By defining the zero locus of an ideal $I \subset A(Y)$ to be the zero locus of $f^{-1}(I)$, the author is saying that the zero locus of $I$ is the zero locus of an ideal $J$ of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ that contains $I(Y)$. This implies that any common zero of the elements of $J$ must be a common zero of the elements of $I(Y)$, hence the zero locus of $J$ is contained in the zero locus of $I(Y)$, which is $Y$.

Comment: I think your answer makes alot of sense, but its still the last part that I don't get. Why does the zero locus of $I(Y)$ equal $Y$?

By the notes I am reading, the zero locus of $I(Y)$ equals the closure of $Y$. Would be mind explaining a little about what the closure of $Y$ actually is (in this specific zariski topology)? Thanks in advance, and great answer.

Comment: Well, since $Y$ is assumed to be an affine variety, it is a closed set (more specifically, it is an irreducible closed set) in the Zariski topology.